# Updating Publication list with SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, cloudpage

We were requested to create a dynamic subscription/unsubscription center using Cloudpages on Marketing Cloud.

We're trying to implement this using SSJS, but code does not work (throws "Error"):

SSJS

```
<script runat=server>
  Platform.Load("core","1");
  var newSubscriber = {
    "EmailAddress": "test@example.com",
    "SubscriberKey": "test@example.com",
    "EmailTypePreference": "Text",
    "Attributes":{ "First Name": "test.1", "Last Name": "test.1" },
    "Lists": {"Status": "Active", "ID": "1****8", "Action": "Update"}
  };
  var status = Subscriber.Upsert(newSubscriber);
  Write(status);
</script>
```

We tried both lists and publication lists (being the second one our main goal).

What's wrong with this code? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_subscriberUpsert.htm) you need to call the init function on the Subscriber object first.

```
<script runat=server>
  Platform.Load("core","1");
  var newSubscriber = {
    EmailAddress: "test@example.com",
    SubscriberKey: "test@example.com",
    EmailTypePreference: "HTML",
    Attributes:{ "First Name": "test.1", "Last Name": "test.1" },
    Lists: {"Status": "Active", "ID": 12345, "Action": "Upsert"}
  };
  var subObj = Subscriber.Init("test@example.com");
  var status = subObj.Upsert(newSubscriber);
  Write(status);
</script>
```

I tested the above and it upserts to a publist successfully. I actually find that using [WSProxy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_WSProxy_update.htm) much more flexible and simpler to use, but it's personal preference. Here's an example:

```
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("core","1.1.5");
    var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
    var options = {SaveOptions: [{'PropertyName': '*', SaveAction: 'UpdateAdd'}]};

    var props = { 
        SubscriberKey: 'test@email.com',
        EmailAddress: 'test@email.com',
        Lists: [{
            ID: 12345,
            Status: 'Active'
        }]
    };
    var data = prox.updateItem('Subscriber', props, options);
    Write(data.Results[0].StatusCode);
</script>
```

Comment: How do I do the same using DE. So If I have email address in DE using the above SSJS how do I achieve the same task?

Comment: Use a [Lookup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_dataExtensionRowsLookup.htm) function for that (or Rows.Retrieve). Hopefully you have both email and subscriber key in your DE. Then use those variable values in place of the static values in the example above.